# How to enable bash-completion xrdp lxde

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, bash-completion, xrdp

It maybe evident for many people but for me wasn't. 
So to enable bash-completion or in other words auto-completion or auto-fill in Linuks OS, Debian or Kali or Ubuntu combine with xlde Desktop Environment and xrdp remote connection :

```
root@station:~# nano /etc/profile
```

at the end of file
add

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

so it looks like:

```
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi

#enable bash-completion for all
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

save file, close terminal and open again.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a rpm installed.

```
bash-completion.noarch
```

I have tried that in RHEL7 and it worked for me.